# How to pass Input parameters from api gateway to document incident manager

Tags: python, api, postman, aws-api-gateway, aws-ssm

How to pass input parameter in incident manager document . I have python script :

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
import re
import boto3
from botocore.vendored import requests
import json
import datetime
import sys
def script_handler(events, context):
 
 ticketid = events['parameter']
 
 
 assigned_to = events['assigned_to']
 url = "https://xyz-abc.com/api/rtxy/incident/update"
 if assigned_to == "yes":
    payload = json.dumps({
        "number": ticketid,
        "work_notes": "test"
    })
 else:
    payload = json.dumps({
         "number": ticketid,
         "state":"6",
         "work_notes":"Changing the Incident Status to Resolved",
         "resolution_code":"Closed/Resolved by Caller",
         "resolution_notes":"Alert resolved in NOI"
    })
 headers = {
   'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXX==',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 }
 response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
 print(response.text)
 print(ticketid)
 print(assigned_to)
```

But when i hit in postmand its giving me error of input parameter require Postman URL example : https://xyzabc-api.us-south-1.amazonaws.com/Test?DocumentName=automation&IncidentID=INC0012345&Assigned=yes&Status=open

Outout received :

"Code": "InvalidAutomationExecutionParameters", "Message": "Missing required parameter: IncidentID in user inputs.", "Type": "Sender"

Comment: Would you please fix the formatting and remove typos. Thx.

Comment: I have updated the same..

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
import re
import boto3
from botocore.vendored import requests
import json
import datetime
import sys
def script_handler(events, context):
 
 ticketid = events['parameter']
 
 
 assigned_to = events['assigned_to']
 url = "https://xyz-abc.com/api/rtxy/incident/update"
 if assigned_to == "yes":
    payload = json.dumps({
        "number": ticketid,
        "work_notes": "test"
    })
 else:
    payload = json.dumps({
         "number": ticketid,
         "state":"6",
         "work_notes":"Changing the Incident Status to Resolved",
         "resolution_code":"Closed/Resolved by Caller",
         "resolution_notes":"Alert resolved in NOI"
    })
 headers = {
   'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXX==',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 }
 response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
 print(response.text)
 print(ticketid)
 print(assigned_to)
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].